# Token for full path in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, filesystem-access

I am configuring custom commands in Texmaker, I can use `%` as a token for the name of the file (minus the extension) but I cannot find an equivalent for the full path.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid such a token might not exist. The Texmaker manual, section 1.2 *Configuring the latex related commands* only mentions these tokens:

> The **%** character represents the name of the file without the extension (the master document in the "master" mode) and the **@** character will be replaced by the current line number.
>   Additional parameter : **#** will be replaced by the current file name without extension (even in the "master" mode)

But you can see if there's a similar feature request on the [Texmaker issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list) already, and if not, file one.

Comment: I've added a feature request: https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=496

Comment: @Ben Your feature request seems to have been deleted -- did you get any feedback why?

Comment: I don't remember - I haven't kept any of the emails so I couldn't say. I seem to recall that people misunderstood the subtle problem and said I was mistaken for adding it.

Comment: ...I seem to recall that people misunderstood the subtle problem (Opening the PDF in Foxit Reader if FR was already open), or thought that I was mistaken and that such a token would never be necessary under any circumstance. Presumably the working directory of the reader is set to the directory containing the PDF, so that a full path is not necessary - except if the reader is already open in which case it fails.